# Taking long time and has no output with the stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am executing the following stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pn_s_pnl.`Takeoffone`()
 BEGIN
SELECT 
 ( select service_display_nm from billing_services_t) as bundle ,
 (select product_type_nm from billing_product_type_t) as package 
 ;
END;
```

But it is taking long time  and there is no result,while i am executing the statements individually,

```
select service_display_nm from billing_services_t;
select product_type_nm from billing_product_type_t
```

I am getting the result soon,Is the stored procedure is incapable of returning all the rows of that column,I am not getting.

Comment: How many records do you get back for each result. Seems like, if there are a lot of records in both queries, that you would end up with a monster cartesian product result. Like if bill_services_t has 1000 records and bill_product_type_t has 5000 records, then you would end up with `1000*5000=5,000,000`. Feels like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: What are you trying to get for results? It looks like you are missing a `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote it as,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pn_s_pnl.`Takeoffone`()
 BEGIN
select service_display_nm from billing_services_t as bundle ;
 select product_type_nm from billing_product_type_t as package 
;
END;
```

This is working fine.